# Python: Remove duplicate objects from a list of JSON objects with unique fields

Tags: python, json, list, object, duplicates

I have retrieved the following JSON from MongoDB using PyMongo. Some fields like `filepath` are unique for each object.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "614c342ad3c1c8e2945c8668"
        },
        "album": "Come Over When You're Sober, Pt. 2",
        // some other fields
        "filepath": "/music/.../....flac"
    },
    {
        // some other objects
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "614c342dd3c1c8e2945c8c8c"
        },
        "album": "Come Over When You're Sober, Pt. 2",
        // some other fields
        "filepath": "/videos/...mp3"
    }
]
```

I want to remove duplicates from this list by checking the album fields for each object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to keep? The first element or the last?

Comment: Copy the records into a dictionary with `album` as the key.  That will only keep the last one.

Comment: `out = list({record['album']: record for record in records}.values())`